# SQL: Using the result of a query in something similar to a FOR EACH loop. MS SQL SMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in several views that I would like to run a check against for computed data.
The first step involves a query that returns several rows with a *VehicleID* column that should be used in the "for each" aspect of the next query, this example has been simplified.

The next step gets the entries from the view [dbo].[viewDataVehicle] that match the *VehicleID* and returns a row with the *VehicleID*, *Timestamp* and *Speed*.

From here I need to calculate the average of these "Speed" values and then select all rows where *Speed* > *AverageSpeed* + *SpeedVariable*(that should be set in the query).
The result should output the entry rows if the condition is met with an additional OverAverage column (lets say it's a boolean TRUE or FALSE, which is this example would all be TRUE).

This is repeated for each of the other *VehicleID*s and the final result is a table containing all the rows that matched the conditions.

I can group by and format later on so this aspect is not important.

How would I write a query to do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and your current attempt. As it stanrds, your question is too vague to be precisely answered.

Comment: Thinking in loops is the last thing you want to do when working with SQL. SQL is a set-based language, and you want to use set-based solutions. Looping, such as using a `WHILE` or `CURSOR`, should only be used as a last resort or when batching is actually more performant (and then we're likely dealing with 100M's of rows).

Comment: Try to improve your question using the suggestions here, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info 
particularly around sample data, DDL, DML and expected output. If you put the effort into providing all the relevant details in your question, I'm sure you'll get a great answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in SQL Select statements wheere-ever you have a From TableName you can substitute another select statement for TableName. So, start with selecting your vehicle id's:

```
select vehicleId
from <table>
where <whatever>
```

Now match to your view:

```
select vdv.vehicleId, Timestamp, speed
from dbo.viewDataVehicle vdv
inner join
(
    select vehicleId
    from <table>
    where <whatever
) v on v.vehicleId = vdv.vehicleId
```

Now use this as input to your next step, and so on and so n.

As Lamu says in a comment, with SQL **never think of individual rows: always think of sets**. RAT (or Row at a Time) is not the way to go.

Comment: This put me on the right track, turns out the concept I was looking for was a CTE with a join as you alluded to in the next section.